# Ink to math converting application

Tags: touchpad, touchscreen, editing

Is there any application (for Ubuntu) allowing to recognize and convert hand drawn math formulas?

I would like to write formulas on paper and scan it, or
to use a drawing touch pad.

Is there any application that convert the formulas directly to Latex code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570220/ocr-lib-for-math-formulas

An online demo:http://cat.prhlt.upv.es/mer/

Comment: You can also look at this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233963/convert-mathtype-and-ms-word-equations-equations-to-latex